# elasticsearch sort by _doc for scroll not returning any results

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to run a scroll query and get the results by sorting on "_doc" field. But the scroll is always returning empty resultest. Below the scroll i am trying. I am using elasticsearch version 2.3.4

```
SearchResponse scrollResp = client.prepareSearch(indexName).setTypes(indexType)
        .setScroll(TimeValue.timeValueMillis(scrollTimeout))
        .addSort("_doc" , SortOrder.ASC)
        .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
        .setQuery(query)
        .setFrom(pageIndex)
        .setSize(scrollSize)
        //.setFetchSource(true)
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
return scrollResp;
```

But if i replace the same query with sort on "id" field it works fine. Am i doing anything wrong here?

```
    SearchResponse scrollResp = client.prepareSearch(indexName).setTypes(indexType)
            .setScroll(TimeValue.timeValueMillis(scrollTimeout))
            .addSort(new FieldSortBuilder("id"))
            .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
            .setQuery(query)
            .setFrom(pageIndex)
            .setSize(scrollSize)
            //.setFetchSource(true)
            .execute()
            .actionGet();
    return scrollResp;
```

Comment: What ES version? How does the responses look like in both cases?

Comment: I am using elasticsearch version 2.3.4